# Why is there no :: Operator on scala map?

Tags: scala

when using Scala immutable lists I can easily do

```
1 :: List(2, 3, 4)
```

and this gives me a new list and I am still using immutable data structures.

So why can't I do

```
(1 -> 1) :: Map(2 -> 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's there; it's just called `+`.

```
scala> Map(2 -> 2) + (1 -> 1)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 2, 1 -> 1)
```

They're fairly different functions, so I don't think it's odd for them to be named them differently. `::` merely constructs a cons cell (it is literally a constructor - [`::` is a case class that extends `List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.html)), whereas `Map`'s `+` has more complex behavior, either adding a new mapping or replacing an existing one depending on the values of the keys in the map.

The name `::` is an allusion to `:` from languages like Haskell, and the name `+` is consistent with the `+` method on `Set`, which is a somewhat common informal mathematical notation.

Comment: but why the inconsistency? surely the :: is not the same as +

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch It doesn't do the exact same thing. An "append" to a `Map` might actually overwrite a key.

Comment: Also, `::` is `List`-specific but there is a more general `+:` for all `Seq`s (and `:+` for appending to the end).